# Fetched Results Controller - Grouping objects into sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6

New to core data stuff, stuck in a bit tricky situation. I've got table with columns:

item, value

And in it some data:

email-home, abc@xyz.com

email-work, xyz@abc.com

phone-home, 1234567890

phone-work, 0987654321

address-home, London

address-work, Edinburgh

I'm trying to have a fetched results controller (FRC), that groups above data from the table into following sections:

section 1:

phone-home, 1234567890

phone-work, 0987654321

section 2:

email-home, abc@xyz.com

email-work, xyz@abc.com

section 3:

address-home, London

address-work, Edinburgh

Can anyone please help how to create sort descriptor (s) that can achieve this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another attribute `sectionnum` of type "Integer 16" to your entity:

```
sectionnum, item, value
-----------------------
2, email-home, abc@xyz.com
2, email-work, xyz@abc.com
1, phone-home, 1234567890
1, phone-work, 0987654321
3, address-home, London
3, address-work, Edinburgh
```

Then you use `sectionnum` as key in the (first) sort descriptor and for the section name key path:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YourEntity"];
NSSortDescriptor *s1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectionnum" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = @[s1];

fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                     managedObjectContext:self.context
                       sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionnum"
                                cacheName:nil];
```